# java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcreator

I just want my record day wise, with sum of rate , tax & amount but differentiate it acc to tax, i.e.5% tax entries of a day sum up & in different row & 13% tax entries with sum will be a diff. row.

```
    try {

        Connection con=Conn.getConnection();
        Statement ps=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("Select Store, InvoiceDate, sum(Rate*quantity), Percen, sum(Tax*Quantity), sum(Amount) from Orders Group By InvoiceDate, Store, Percen");

        while(rs.next()){

            v=new Vector();

            v.add(rs.getString(1));
            v.add(converToString(rs.getDate(2)));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(3));
            v.add(rs.getString(4));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(5));
            v.add(rs.getDouble(6));

            mDateWise.addRow(v);
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(c,ex.toString());
    }
```

It's showing error java.sql.SQLException: No data found . help!!

Comment: no error in query. no syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching String and Date both from index `1` , How is that possible

```
rs.getString(1); <--- String Value at index 1
rs.getDate(1)); <---- Date  Value at index 1
```